# What are the user permissions needed to enable snapshot isolation in a DB?

Tags: database, sql-server-2008, isolation-level

I have a user who has db_datareader, db_datawriter permissions on a DB. 
I want to set the isolation levels to the DB to which the user has access to.
What permissions will my user need to be able to set these.
DB used: SQL SERVER 2008

Comment: yes, I was trying to set the isolation levels with the user who has only the above mentioned permissions and it threwa an error that the permissions are not enough

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is not setting an isolation level:

```
ALTER DATABASE dbname SET ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION ON;
```

That is altering the database. For that you need to provide them with `ALTER` rights on the database:

```
GRANT ALTER ON DATABASE::dbname TO username;
```

Otherwise you get this error:

> Msg 5011, Level 14, State 9, Line 1
>   
> User does not have permission to alter database 'dbname', the database does not exist, or the database is not in a state that allows access checks.
>   
> Msg 5069, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   
> ALTER DATABASE statement failed.

Now, `ALTER` is all or nothing - you can't use it to allow them to change the allow snapshot setting but not other settings like forced parameterization, compatibility level, etc. You can do this much more granularly, though; perhaps you could create a stored procedure that does something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.SetIsolationLevel
WITH EXECUTE AS OWNER
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'ALTER DATABASE ' 
      + QUOTENAME(DB_NAME())
      + ' SET ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION ON;';

  EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
END
GO
```

Now you just have to give the user `EXEC` permissions on that procedure, which your user can now call (instead of the `ALTER DATABASE` command explicitly and instead of giving them full `ALTER DATABASE` privileges):

```
GRANT EXEC ON dbo.SetIsolationLevel TO username;
GO
```

You can simulate them calling this stored procedure by logging in as them, or using the `EXECUTE AS` feature directly:

```
EXECUTE AS USER = 'username';
GO
EXEC dbo.SetIsolationLevel;
GO
REVERT;
GO
```

Another idea is to simply set the `model` database to have this setting, than any new databases that get created for your users will automatically inherit it, then you don't have to worry about making them turn it on.

```
ALTER DATABASE model SET ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION ON;
GO
CREATE DATABASE splunge;
GO
SELECT snapshot_isolation_state_desc FROM sys.databases WHERE name = N'splunge';
```

Result:

```
ON
```

Comment: I am trying to set the isolation level through a JDBC program. This program takes the user name and password, connects using these and then tries to run the alter statement.
ALTER DATABASE <DBNAME> SET ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION ON;

Comment: That is different from what your question says. Your question talks about setting isolation levels. You are actually talking about changing a database property.

Comment: sorry for the confusion, but I am indeed trying to set the isolation level. These are the 2 statements I am trying to run:
ALTER DATABASE <DBNAME> SET ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION ON;
ALTER DATABASE <DBNAME> SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT ON;

But when I run these I am ending up with the error you mentioned above related to the permissions.

Comment: @user811433 once again, your attempt to set the isolation level is not failing; your attempt to set the database's ability to use a certain isolation level is failing. I just gave you three alternate ways to get past that error: grant the user alter database, create a stored procedure that acts as dbo on their behalf to set the setting, or have the database inherit that setting upon creation from model. While I'm sure there may be other ways to get where you need to be, what is wrong with these choices? How many more alternatives do you expect there to be?